# LaTeX Package ctable and Saucy Salamander

Tags: 13.10, latex

I have a number of LaTeX documents that use the package `ctable` in the header. Upon updating Ubuntu to Saucy Salamander, these documents have refused to compile, TexMaker returning the error:

"! No room for a new \dimen".

Upon commenting out the call to use this package, the document compiles fine (albeit, more slowly than before the update). Note that the particular document I have tested does not use any commands (that I am aware of) which rely on `ctable`.

Now [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+package/liblatex-table-perl) page says something about Saucy Salamander and this package, indicating the updater might have changed some settings or something. Do I need to install/re-install/overwrite anything in order to ensure that my LateX functions properly in Saucy Salamander?

Answer (score 1):

ctable package is in the ubuntu package 'texlive-latex-recommended', installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended
```

I figured it out by searching in the package archives descriptions:

```
apt-get search ctable.*latex
```

Note: the search is done with regular expression.

ctable.*latex => ctable followed one or more characters, follow by latex